# Best way to setup an Ecto Schema for a two-way, many-to-many relationship with itself

Tags: elixir, many-to-many, ecto

For the `tasks` schema below, I'm trying to add linking tasks to one another with a `many_to_many` relationship joined through a `task_links` table.

```
schema "tasks" do
  field :title, :integer
  field :description, :string
  belongs_to :assignee, User
  timestamps()
end
```

The `task_links` table is setup as follows:

```
def change do
  create table(:task_links) do
    add :left_task_id, references(:tasks)
    add :right_task_id, references(:tasks)
    add :creator_id, references(:users)
    timestamps()
  end

  create constraint(:task_links, :left_less_than_right_check, check: "left_task_id < right_task_id")
  create unique_index(:task_links, [:left_task_id, :right_task_id])
end
```

The check constraint and unique index are used to ensure links aren't duplicated.

My question is, what is the best way to alter the `tasks` schema (or my approach to linking tasks) so queries preloading the `task_links` association return a list of linked tasks?

The issues is a task's `id` can be in the `:left_task_id` or `:right_task_id` column of the `task_links` table. I've almost achieved my goal with two many-to-many relationships:

```
schema "tasks" do
  ...
  many_to_many :right_links, Task, join_through: TaskLinks, join_keys: [left_task_id: :id, right_task_id: :id]
  many_to_many :left_links, Task, join_through: TaskLinks, join_keys: [right_task_id: :id, left_task_id: :id]
end
```

This setup is close to what I'm aiming for, but the query below returns links separately depending on whether the target task's `id` was in the `:left_task_id` or `right_task_id` column of the `task_links` table:

```
def get_task_and_links(task_id) do
  from(t in Task,
    left_join: right in assoc(t, :right_links),
    left_join: left in assoc(t, :left_links),
    preload [right_links: right, left_links: left]
    where: t.id == ^task_id
  ) |> Repo.one
-----------------
iex(1)> Tasks.get_task_and_links(6)
%Task{
  id: 6,
  ...,
  left_links: [
    %Task{id: 4, ...},
    %Task{id: 5, ...}
  ],
  right_links: [
    %Task{id: 32, ...}
  ]
```

Is there a way I could setup my `tasks` schema (or change my method of linking tasks) so a query would return a list of every task linked to a task under a single field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone interested, I simplified things by representing an undirected link between tasks A and B as two directed links, A → B and B → A. For my use case, duplicating data is a perfectly acceptable tradeoff. Now I just join on the `:left_task_id` (renamed to `:task_id`) column.

```
# TaskLinks Migration
def change do
  create table(:task_links) do
    add :task_id, references(:tasks)
    add :linked_task_id, references(:tasks)
    add :creator_id, references(:users)
    timestamps()
  end

  create unique_index(:task_links, [:left_task_id, :right_task_id])
end
-----------------
# Tasks Schema
schema "tasks" do
  ...
  has_many :task_links, TaskLinks, foreign_key: :task_id
end
-----------------
def get_task_and_links(task_id) do
  from(t in Task,
  left_join: link in assoc(t, :task_links),
  preload: [task_links: link],
  where: t.id == ^task_id
) |> Repo.one

iex(1)> Tasks.get_task_and_links(6)
%Task{
  id: 6,
  ...,
  task_links: [
    %Task{id: 4, ...},
    %Task{id: 5, ...},
    %Task{id: 32, ...}
  ]
}
```